# Finding my home?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok so I've been playing on survival for awhile now. And I go wondering  to look for needed materials and I get lost and can't find my house. This had happend to me twice now. Is there anyway to spawn where my house is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sleeping in a [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) will set your spawn point to where that bed is.

From the wiki:

> Once the player has entered the bed, the spawn point is set near the bed.

Comment: I've only got a bed with me?

Comment: Well, you put the bed in your home. Sleep in it, leave it there, and the next time you die, you'll re-spawn beside your bed. If that's what you were asking?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I can find me home.

Comment: If you die, will you know how to get back to your home from the initial spawn?

Comment: I don't think so...my house was far from the initial spawn...

Comment: try using `/gamemode creative` in the console to switch to creative mode, then fly around until you recognize a landmark.

Comment: Another tip: once you do find your home, hit F3 (in the PC version) to view your coordinates (XYZ). Write these down or something, and then if you get lost you can use the F3 display to get yourself to the coordinates of your base.